# Bayesian estimation from sum of two random variables

Tags: distributions, bayesian, random-variable

Let's say I have a set of observations $Y=\{Y_1,\ldots,Y_N\}$ where each observation is created as the sum of two random variables, i.e. $Y_i=X_{1,i}+X_{2,i}$. Also, I know that $X_1 \sim Dist_1(\theta_1)$ and $X_2\sim Dist_2(\theta_2)$ (e.g. $Dist_1(\theta_1)=Normal(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $Dist_2(\theta_2)=Exponential(\lambda)$). Is there a way to estimate the parameters $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ based on the observations of only $Y$?

1) In order to estimate the parameters, I would need the likelihood function $L(\theta_1,\theta_2;Y)$, which has to be derived from the individual likelihoods of $Dist_1$ and $Dist_2$. If I can get an analytical formula for these distributions, I could, of course, use that to get the likelihood by convolution. But what if one of the likelihoods is more complicated.

2) Also, I could draw samples from one of the distribution, then subtract and use this to get the likelihood from the second distribution. But that would mean that I have to draw one additional sample for each $Y_i$ so the computational cost is increased.

Is there a better way for this?

**EDIT**:

Some clarifications:

1. I assume identifiability in the sense that if we let $Dist_3=Dist_1(\theta_1)+Dist_2(\theta_2)$ be the distribution of $Y$ then for any other pair $\tilde{\theta_1}$ and $\tilde{\theta_2}$ with
   $\tilde{\theta_1}\neq\theta_1$ and/or $\tilde{\theta_2}\neq\theta_2$ we have 
   $Dist_3\neq Dist_1(\tilde{\theta_1})+Dist_2(\tilde{\theta_2)}$. Thus, for example if $Dist_1$ and $Dist_2$ were bot normal distribution this would not be identifyable (one could simply set $\tilde{\theta_1}=\theta_2$ and $\tilde{\theta_2}=\theta_1$). Therefore, the example with a gaussian and a exponential would be identifyable, e.g. by fitting an ex-gaussian.
2. My question is concerned more with a general how to implement something like this in a Bayesian sampler. The actual distributions I have are much more complicated (resulting from a cognitive model). The papers I looked at usually use numerical integration to calculate the convolution, but I would be grateful for a way to reduce the computational costs.

Comment: The answer depends on the details.  For instance, when both distributions are Normal (and independent), you cannot identify all the parameters, but in other cases you can.

Comment: @whuber Ok, thank you for pointing this out. I edited the question to clarify this. I am assuming that in theory, the parameters are identifiable, such that I could always calculate the convolution and get the required log-likelihood. The question is more about if it is possible at all to get around the convolution somehow.